# how to pass to argument to parent class from grand child class or sub class

Tags: java, superclass

I am having parent class `P` that has constructor in it with an argument. I am having child class `C` that extends `P` and then I am having another sub child class `Sc` that extends `C`.

for example

parent class

```
class P {

    Settings settings

    public P(Settings settings) {
        this.settings = settings
    }
}

class C extends P {

  Settings settings

   public C(Settings settings) {
   super(settings)
   this.settings = settings
  }
}

class Sc extends C {

      Settings settings

       public Sc(Settings settings) {
       super(settings)
       this.settings = settings
      }
    }
```

here I am able to pass the argument to the constructor from class C to class P but not from class Sc to class c and to class P. how can I pass argument to the super class from grand child class ?

Comment: What you have works perfectly fine ? you can pass argument to super class via 'super' just like you are doing. Do you get any error message ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call

> super(setting)

in your child constructor.